# I want to search from an array inside an array? See the example

Tags: ios, search, swift4, nspredicate

I have to search from an array inside an array. But I am unable to do it. See the example of array:

```
[
    {
        "hospital_name": "Medical Hospital", 
        "address": "1/127 India ", 
        "facilities_data": [
            {
                "name": "Speciality", 
                "facilities_list": [
                    {
                        "facilities_name": "Andrology"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "facilities_name": "Cosmetology"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Facilities", 
                "facilities_list": [
                    {
                        "facilities_name": "ICU"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "facilities_name": "Multispeciality"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "facilities_name": "OPD"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "facilities_name": "Physical Therapy"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have to search with **hospital_name, address & facilities_name**

I am doing this right now, where I am getting successful result for **hospital_name & address**. ***But not for facilities_name***.

```
func getAllSearchedArrayList(txt: String) {
      let namePredicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "hospital_name contains[c] %@ || facilities_name contains[c] %@ || address contains[c] %@", txt, txt, txt);        
      var searchedArray1: Array<Any>!
      searchedArray1 = self.hospitalArray.filter { namePredicate1.evaluate(with: $0) };
      self.searchedHospitalArray = searchedArray1
      if self.searchedHospitalArray.count == 0 {
          self.hospitalTableView.reloadData()
      }
      else {
          self.hospitalTableView.reloadData()
      }
  }
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `... facilities_data.facilities_list.facilities_name contains[c] %@ ...`?  Why are you using `contains` instead of `==` as it's not the same thing?  If you don't have to use `NSPredicate` then I would dump it and just write search code as I find that easier to understand than this pseudo-SQL nonsense...

Answer (score 0):

Construct your array into structs like so:

```
    struct Hospital{
        let hospital_name : String!
        let address : String!
        let facilities_Data : [Facilities_Data]!
    }

    struct Facilities_Data{
        let name : String!
        let facilities_list : [String]!
    }

    var hospitals = [Hospital]()    // parse your array to struct first
    var filteredHospitals = hospitals     // use filteredHospitals to fill your tableview data instead of the original hospitals array to keep the original data intact.

    func getAllSearchedArrayList(searchText: String){

        //reuse original data if no searchText else starts to filter

        filteredHospitals = searchText.isEmpty ? hospitals : hospitals.filter({ (hospital) -> Bool in
            return hospital.hospital_name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil || hospital.address.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil || hospital.facilities_Data.contains(where: { (data) -> Bool in
                return data.facilities_list.contains(where: { (name) -> Bool in
                    return name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
                })
            })
        })
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

The main idea here is to address your horrible array of dictionary, and make them into smaller chunks of code and recognizable type, so that you can use that particular type to search. (String using range(of:) in this case.

I personally use this in conjuncture with search bar delegate : search(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) as it allows user to see the result every time they type into the search bar instead of typing whole string out just to see there is no result, this way the tableview will constantly refresh and show lesser and lesser result.